# How to make "category on id"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories

Please, don't take this literally, but how could I do such thing as "category on id"? I want to have a method available on object of type ID, how to do that? My situation is that I have dictionary received from API, and I want to do something like this:

```
someVariable = [dictionary[@"key"] myValue];
```

Method myValue should be similar to for example intValue - which is available on objects of type id. Any ideas?

Comment: You should try to categorize NSObject instead, I think that this will have the same effect and it'll be easier.

Comment: Nearest to the metal you're going to get is a category of `NSObject`.

Comment: I dont know guys, I've tried that but the method isnt available

Comment: Why dont you do a category on the NSDictionary something like myValueForKey that returns myValue for a given key... Will that work for you?

Comment: that's interesting :) gonna try

Comment: I think you should stick strongly typed objects as much as you can. The method you are trying to apply is easy to produce but prone to errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a category on `id` because it isn't a class.  It is just a pointer type -

```
typedef struct objc_object *id;
```

As others have suggested in the comments, you can add a category on `NSObject` -

```
@interface NSObject (myCategory)
    -(MyObjectType *)myValue;
@end
```

**BUT** you can't declare additional properties on an object using a category.

My gut feel is that you have a design problem that would be better solved using an appropriate wrapper class for your data objects.

Comment: you don't need to cast the `dictionary` object as `NSObject`, every class is inherited from that one.